In Geometric Algebra, is the handedness of a coordinate system defined implicitly?
Is it true that their is a concept of handedness in a geomtric algebra. I feel like its something to do with the anticommutativity of separate vectors, but regardless, is there a reasoning to it? How does one setup right-handed algorithims vs left-handed algorithims in for example $\mathbb{R}_{3,0,1}$?

Right-handed versus left-handed algorithms may be a distinction without a difference.  The short section starting on p. 2 of https://bivector.net/PGA4CS.pdf suggests that this sign convention is more "tribal" than real.  (It may help to know that plane-based geometric algebra is a $(3,0,1)$ GA.  See the table at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_algebra#Table_of_models )  Also, one expects to reverse orientation by reflecting the universe through (any) plane, so any algorithm should be both a left- and right-handed form...

So is it kind of like all the operations in geometric algebra aren't related to the handedness at all, so its pointless to label it with one until you maybe render it out or implement a mapping to some matrix representation or something? Does this mean the anti-commutativity is more to do with orthogonality?

Geometric algebra does not really play a part here.
In arbitrary dimensions every ordered basis has one of two orientations. Two ordered bases $e_1,\dotsc,e_n$ and $f_1,\dotsc,f_n$ have the same orientation if the linear transformation defined by $e_i\mapsto f_i$ has positive determinant. In geometric algebra terms, this is equivalent to the existence of a positive scalar $\alpha$ such that
$$
  e_1\wedge\dotsb\wedge e_n = \alpha f_1\wedge\dotsc\wedge f_n.
$$
If there is a negative $\alpha$ then the bases have opposite orientation. Swapping any two adjacents basis vectors gives you the opposite orientation since e.g.
$$
  e_1\wedge e_2\wedge e_3\wedge\dotsb\wedge e_n = -e_2\wedge e_1\wedge e_3\wedge\dotsb\wedge e_n
$$
"Handedness" is a slightly more specific concept that only exists in 3D. A basis $e_1, e_2, e_3$ is right-handed if there is a positive scalar $\alpha$ such that $e_1\times e_2 = \alpha e_3$ (using the usual cross product), and is left-handed if there is a negative $\alpha$. Two bases with the same handedness necessarily have the same orientation, so requiring a specific handedness is just a way of choosing an orientation.

What determines the default orientation, does it matter what the orientation is? For example is it dumb to think of $e_{12}$ as "the positive one" and $e_{21}$ as "the negative one"?

Nothing, it is completely arbitrary.

@ConorOMalley : A similar thing happens when mapping the algebra of polynomials to the complex plane.  Algebraically, we designate one of the two roots of $x^2 + 1 = 0$ with "$\mathrm{i}$", but "which is which" is algebraically unanswerable.  When we carry this over to a complex plane, we have to decide which root gets mapped to $(0,1) = 0 + 1\mathrm{i}$ and one choice can be turned into the other by reflecting the plane through the real axis -- so two settings that made opposite choices can be reconciled by a reflection.
